# HW_PROFILE_INFO Windows 8.1 bug

Tags: c++, guid, hwid

I'm using this piece of code to unique identity the computers, but it seems it doesn't work properly on Windows 8.1.

```
HW_PROFILE_INFO HwProfInfo;
if (!GetCurrentHwProfile(&HwProfInfo))
    return;

std::wstring ws(HwProfInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
std::string GUID(ws.begin(), ws.end());

printf("%s\n", GUID.c_str());
```

Every Windows 8.1 computer generate this GUID:

**{bbed3e02-0b41-11e3-8249-806e6f6e6963}**

How is it possible or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to hardware profiles which were eliminated in Windows 7 (IIRC). This value is only a handle to the *current hardware profile* should one exist, and should be used for configuration settings only and not a key for uniquely identifying systems.

For that and later versions of windows it always returns the same values; I expect it still passes in order to prevent unexpected app failures.

This value should never have been used for uniquely identifying computers as it was intended for managing settings that vary when the system was docked/undocked/had a different profile applied.